# How to click back and return to previous activity state

Tags: java, android, android-activity, baseadapter

In my android app, I have implemented activity A which has a BaseAdapter that holds the listview. When I click on an item, it moves to activity B through an intent. When I press the back button, it returns to activity A, which is running properly although I get no views. I believe that it has to do with the BaseAdapter and the data stored are lost. Do you have any ideas on how to keep view as I left it before I press the button? I could only find the parcelable method, but I would like to know if there is another way.

EDIT:

```
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(activityA.this, activityB.class);
     startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: It depends on what you loaded in the list in your onCreate and how you opened your second activity. You should post your code so we can check it

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori I have edited the topic.

Comment: Override backpress and start the activitya again

Comment: @kgandroid I want to find the listview as it was before the launch of activity B

Comment: @TinaLooke You don't need to re initialise `mAdapter` and set it as list adapter.. try moving it to `onCreate()` in `onResume() ` just update array/arraylist and call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` for updating list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the initialization in onCreate and called mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() as Jaiprakash Soni pointed out. Everything works ok now.